# How to creates HTML div boxes at specific coordinate, following a leaflet map?

Tags: html, dom, leaflet, coordinates

In an attempt to assemble a simple interactive map, I'm trying to create multiple HTML elements (boxes filled with text, images, etc.) on specific coordinates of an interactive Leaflet map.
I'd like to be able to modify these elements using JS code, and they should follow the map (movable and zoomable).

I've managed to create a few L.rectangles where I need them, but I can't fill them with HTML elements.
Is it possible to insert something inside these L.rectangles or L.polygons (thus following the map)?
I haven't managed to do much more than change the visual properties of these vectors.

I've tried to create another layer above the main map using L.GridLayer.extend but I can't figure out how to fill it with positioned divs.
The problem is probably very simple to solve but after hours of trying and documenting it, I can't figure it out.
I've resolved to ask for help (at the risk of being laughed at).

Comment: L.Markers with L.DivIcons.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, seems to be a working option ! But how can I link these L.DivIcons to follow the zoom of the map? I don't undertsand how to avoid them keeping their defined size. This is why i started with an option with L.rectangles.